# FormData is empty (in PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form-data

I have been using this to process a form via AJAX and jQuery

```
$("#uploadBtn").click(function()
{
  var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]); //--FormData here, problem line
  $.ajax({
    url: 'resources/ajax/ajax_upload_video.php',
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function()
    {
      xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (xhr.upload)
      {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
      }
      return xhr;
    },
    success: function(msg)
    {
      log(msg);
    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

It has been working fine. I added a second form on the page (Search on top, uploader on bottom)

I understand the `$('form')[0]` will grab the first form on the page, so naturally I changed my javascript to `$('form')[1]`. When I do a console.log on it, it is the correct form.

When I hit the upload button, but my php file says nothing was posted. For simplicity sake, my php file is this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I get just an empty array. I even gave the form I want an ID and called it this way `$('#uploadForm')`.

I have 1 multi-select FILE input, a hidden field and a text input field.

What am I doing wrong with the `FormData` object?

One side not, I've been developing this page locally using WAMP and just moved it to our CentOS server that is online. Could this be a PHP setting that isn't the same as my local environment? I can't think of what PHP setting would have to do with POST

**Upload Form**

```
<form id="videoUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload-form modal-edit-form">
  <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            <div align="center" id="fileSelect">
                <input type="hidden" value="video" name="mediaType" id="mediaType" />
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['reelId']; ?>" name="reelId" id="reelId" />
                <input type="file" name="videos[]" id="videos" accept="video/mp4" multiple />
            </div>
            <br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div id="dropbox">
                <ul class="hide" id="filelist">
                </ul>
                <div align="center" id="nofiles">Select some file to begin</div>
            </div><br>
        </p>

        <p>
            <hr>
            <label>Search Tags <small>[at least two tags separate by comma]</small></label>
            <input type="text" class="span5" name="searchTags" id="searchTags" disabled />
        </p>
        <hr>
        <p align="center">
            <img src="resources/img/loader.gif" class="hide" id="loader" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="uploadBtn" id="uploadBtn" disabled><i class="icon-circle-arrow-up icon-white"></i> Begin Upload</button>
            <div id="successfulUpload" class="alert alert-success hide">
                <b>The videos have been successfully uploaded.</b><br/>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: remove the `processData:false` string and see if it works.

Comment: Are you sure the form uploaded files before? I didn't get it to work with $.ajax before if the form has files and ended up using $.ajaxForm plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: I am positive it was uploading file before @Ohgodwhy did not work

Comment: You can see what trouble $.ajaxform goes through to serialize a form with files to upload http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js. The standard jQuery might work in some browsers. So all the fields are empty when you log the formData? console.log(new FormData($('form')[1]));

Comment: I just went back to local version. Since I've added the search form as I stated in my OP, I changed the JS for the upload form to `var formData = new FormData($('form')[1]);` and it works just fine. This has me thinking its a PHP problem now. The code is identical to what I am running on WAMP

Comment: Ok I figured it out. My PHP settings on the server had a POST_MAX_SIZE of 1M. The video I was uploading was 2. I checked my PHP error log and it didn't have anything in it about going over the max size..weird

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing it this way:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form-id');
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

From [this page](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata) on FormData.

Comment: this is the same technique of passing in a form element.

Comment: could you post your form code? Do you have the required name="fieldname" or ids in there? Might be able to help troubleshoot if we could see the form.

Comment: I've added the html for the upload form